# Zipping files and folders in android

Tags: android, file, zip, directory

So I created a class follwoing the examples found here. http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29 which is great, it works wonders, for files. When it comes to folders it does not work. I tried switching the strings to files and using isDirectory, but it was a no go. Here is the code:

```
import android.util.Log; 
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Compress {

    private static final int BUFFER = 2048;
    private String[] _files;
    private String _zipFile;

    public Compress(String[] files, String zipFile) {
        _files = files;
        _zipFile = zipFile;
    }

    public void zip() {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i]
                        .lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;
                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you manage to make it compress folders too, please contact me, i have the same problem, and didn't manage yet

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399126/java-util-zip-recreating-directory-structure

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it doesn't support adding directories with contents.
So you should manually walk through directory structure and add all files inside directory and subdirectories.