# delete file from .ear file using java program?

Tags: java, zip, war, ear

My folder structure is like this
I have .zip->.ear->.war->folder->xx.jsp file
i want to delete xx.jsp through java code if any one have any ideas.

please help me...

thanks in advance.

Comment: i am using this code for deleting file in zip->.ear->.war

Answer (score 0):

There is a java.util.zip package you can use for this.
Take a look at this post [Recreating Directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399126/java-util-zip-recreating-directory-structure)

Comment: Hi I tried to delete particular file .ear file with in zip but it gave runtime exception that can not able to rename file