# How to download a large Zip from GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, zip, google-cloud-storage, large-files

I used the methods suggested here: 
[Creating ZIP archives in Google App Engine ( Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603201/creating-zip-archives-in-google-app-engine-java) 
And here [How to create a zip archive containing google cloud storage objects within appengine java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871412/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-containing-google-cloud-storage-objects-within-appen)
to return a zip file, the problem I'm having is that the response is bigger than the allowed ~30M. What is the best practice to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most optimal way will be saving to Storage Bucket, and then serve it from there.

It also allows you to:

- prepare file from a TaskQueue job, which is not limited to 60 seconds so you can process much more data, handle errors, etc
- give user ability to pause/resume download, use a download manager, etc, w/o forcing your frontend to start the job from the beginning each time

Basically i'm suggesting:

1. give user an *TicketId* for backend job
2. send task to TaskQueue
3. prepare data in this backend job, upload to Storage Bucket, set *TicketId* as *done*
4. browser waits until *TicketId* is marked as *done* (AJAX of Channel API)
5. then a special servlet gives this file, from a Storage

There're two options to serve this file later:

(optimal) Give a link directly to Storage object:

- https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/[<object>]
- https://<bucket>.storage.googleapis.com/[<object>]
- https://yourdomain.if.set.for.the.bucket/[<object>]

or by using Blobstore:

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/<bucket>/<object>");
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp); //where resp is your HttpServletResponse
```

Comment: If the ZIP file is big won't I have the same issues with the servlet from step 5?

Comment: no, if you're not copying it manually through servlet. see answer update

Comment: My task gets cancelled because I get timeout accessing the GCService. The zip's are huge.

Comment: Oh, you mean 10 minutes is not enough? try to use _manual_ or _basic_ scaling instead of _automatic_, it gives up to 24 hours for a task. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes